# Controls are disabled in MenuItems used in Shell in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The code below when entered in AppShell for Xamarin Forms only works in Android.  In iOS the Switch is rendered but can't be toggled (as if it is disabled).  Are there any tricks to making this work in iOS as well or is this a bug?
I tried placing the the Switch in a completely different ContentView and loading it in the Shell with local: and also tried including the Switch in the DataTemplate directly.  All of them work in Android, just not iOS.
Thanks for your help

```
<MenuItem>
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <Switch IsToggled="True" />
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hi, could you share the version of Visual Studio and Xamarin Forms, and the version of tested iOS device? I will check the problem in my local site.

Comment: Oh, I have tested in my local site with the latest version of Visual Studio(`16.7.6`) and Xamarin Forms(`4.8.0.1`), however the phenomenon is the same with yours. If it's an issue, you could sumbit [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) in Github. Then we can follow it up there.